# Removing a table row dynamically using jquery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

This Table is generating dynamically.

```
<table class='myTab' id='selectPlaceTable' border='1px'>
    <tr>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td><input type='button' class='buttonRmv' id='buttonRmv' value='+'</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

jquery Function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".buttonRmv").on('click',function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
});
```

Comment: try this             $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").remove();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

[Check Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xefr4ajo/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document.body).on('click',".buttonRmv",function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click',".buttonRmv",function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are generating HTML dynamically use **event delegation** and `.closest()` as shown :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document.body).on('click',".buttonRmv",function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click',".buttonRmv",function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```